# Angular2 RxJS calling class function from map function

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I'm new to Angular 2 and Observables so I apologise if my problem is trivial. Anyway I'm trying to test the Angular 2 HTTP Client using RxJS. Although I got it to work I need to add more logic to the service I'm currently working on. Basically I'd like to have a mapping function to convert the object I receive from the web service I'm connected to, to the model object I have in Angular.

This is the code that works:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Person } from '../models/person';

@Injectable()
export class PersonsService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private personsUrl = 'http://localhost/api/persons';

    getPersons(): Observable<Person[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.personsUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        if(res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
            throw new Error('Bad response status ' + res.status);
        }

        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = error.message;
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

With the above code I have no problems whatsoever. The issue I'm having is that I'd like to map the object I'm getting from the service to the one I have in Angular i.e. `Person`. What I tried is to call another function from the `extractData` function that's being used by the `.map` function.

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    if(res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status ' + res.status);
    }

    let body = res.json();
    // map data function
    var data = this.mapData(body.data);

    return data || {};
}

private mapData(data: any) {
    // code to map data
}
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work as when `this` is referenced inside the `extractData` function, `this` does not refer to the `PersonsService` class, but it refers to a `MapSubscriber` object.

I don't know if it is possible to call an "external" function. It might be a silly thing but I can't find any information regarding this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of just passing the `function` reference use [`arrow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions to retain `this`

```
.map((res) => this.extractData(res))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :) Could you explain the reasoning behind it please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions without it `this` will point to the function where the call is made.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out over this. Thanks!

Comment: Ah. Great! This helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: passing this reference as second param to map(fn,this) function will also do the same thing with less verbosity,refer my answer

Comment: Interesting, didn't know. `.map(this.extractData.bind(this))` would also work. I prefer arrow functions everywhere though. Consistency makes it easier to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Observable's map function allows you to pass a reference variable as a second argument on how should `this` actually work inside the higher-order function.
so the **solution** is
       `.map(this.extractData,this)`
This way while passing the extractData function you are also passing the current class's `this` execution context to the higher-order function.
It will work.

[Observable Doc Reference Link](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map)

[image: screenshot of the doc]