# Angular2 subscribe "this" is replaced by SelfSubscriber

Tags: angular

I have a login function in an authorization component that calls a WebAPI method to process the login.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

    let loginRequest = <ILoginRequest>{};
    loginRequest.username = username;
    loginRequest.password = password;

    let loginUrl = this._webApiConfig.rootUrl + ':' + this._webApiConfig.serverPort + this._webApiConfig.authUrl;

    return this._webApiDataContext.post(loginUrl, loginRequest)
        .map(response => { return response.json(); });
}
```

It is called by this:

```
this._authorization.login(this.email, this.password)
    .subscribe(this.success);

success(user) {
    if (user.isAuthorized) {

        // Set the cookie and redirect the user to the dashboard.
        this._cookie.setCookie('auth', JSON.stringify(user), 1);
        this._router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
    }
}
```

When it gets to the success method, 'this' has been replaced with a SafeSubscriber object.  In Angular 1, I used the ControllerAs syntax, but from what I have learned in Angular 2, I don't need to anymore?  None of the examples I have found use anything like it.  I can get it to work if I set a 'vm' variable to equal 'this', but I'm still confused as to why other examples I have seen do not need to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Possible it will be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216807/angular2-rxjs-calling-class-function-from-map-function#answer-37216876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like

```
this._authorization.login(this.email, this.password)
    .subscribe((respJson) => this.success(respJson));

success(user) {
    if (user.isAuthorized) {

        // Set the cookie and redirect the user to the dashboard.
        this._cookie.setCookie('auth', JSON.stringify(user), 1);
        this._router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I was certain it was something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In this case you should use `bind`:

```
...subscribe(this.success.bind(this))
```

or arrow function:

```
 ...subscribe(user => this.success(user))
```